# Put Layout above multiple rows of ListView

Tags: android, listview, user-interface

I am doing app as Google Calendar to add events.

The Google Calendar uses this UI:

[image: Google Calendar]

When you create an Event, it draws a blue Layout(or TextView) to represent the duration of the Event.

I am trying to do that effect. I have my ListView where each row represents one hour.

If I have a Event with 2.5 hour of duration, the Layout must be on 2 and a half rows of the ListView.

How can I draw a single Layout on multiple rows?

I am using a custom ListView with a custom Adapter. I understand when you override getView() in the Adapter, you draw just one row of the list. I don't know if this is the correct approach to do this.

Thanks for your help and sorry for the bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess Google Calendar use custom container instead of `ListView` for doing that. If you take a look at original calendar with switched on "Show layout bounds" or by using `DDMS` you will see following:

[image]

So to achive the same behavior, taking in account that GC Event could be scheduled with 5min precision the best way to achive this is by manualy manipulating views on layout (creating own container for Event views).

Also you could take a look on existing libraries like following:

- [Calendar-Day-View](https://github.com/khacpv/Calendar-Day-View)
- [Android-Week-View](https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View)

Comment: I think I will try with the libraries or create my own view.

Thank you!!